# Summing Audio Channels

Tags: audio, automotive, stereo, summing

I’m trying to sum my car stereo output. Factory output has bass on one output and mid and tweeter on another output giving me 2 channels for left and 2 channels for right.

Ideally I’d like to sum them together and would of used something like a PAC LP7-4 however there doesn’t seem to have any availability in the U.K.

Is it possible to sum them by using 10k resistors and not cause any problems to the factory system?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks Brian Drummond